# How to write the items in a list down a specific column

Tags: python, csv

I have code that writes my list (3 items) repeatedly across columns 1, 2, and 3, and repeats down the csv:

```
list = [13243, 3452345, 234234]

def listplace(in_path):
    file_obj = open(in_path, 'wb')
    writer = csv.writer(file_obj)

    for row in in_path:
        for column in row:
            writer.writerows([list])


    file_obj.close()
```

Here is the output, which overwrites the info I need to keep in column 1:

```
13243   3452345 234234
13243   3452345 234234
13243   3452345 234234
13243   3452345 234234
13243   3452345 234234
13243   3452345 234234
```

I would like to have this as the output (iterate each item till no more info in column 1, with a header):

```
Header  Header
info    13243
info    3452345
info    234234
info    13243
info    3452345
info    234234
info    13243
info    3452345
info    234234
info    13243
info    3452345
info    234234
info    13243
```

Does this require an iterative loop? If so, how might I start it at row 2, column 2?

Comment: Save yourself some typing and write one row at a time with `writer.writerow(list)`.

Comment: is the main difference here the writerow() - no s, or the lack of brackets? What will this edit do differently?

Comment: Both; `writerows()` expects a list of rows, but you pass in just *one*. `writerow()` expects one row.

Comment: Why are you using `in_path` first as a filename, then loop over it?  Where is `info` supposed to *come* from?

Comment: I write over in_path because I have multiple edits to the csv prior to this step, so I was trying to avoid creating a new file for each step.  Info is just values that already exist in the 1st colun prior to this step that I need to preserve

Comment: So you are **adding** columns to an **existing** file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`itertools.cycle()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.cycle) to repeat some information. You can use [`itertools.izip()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.izip) to pair your repeating column with whatever produces values for your first column too:

```
from itertools import izip, cycle

def listplace(in_path):
    with open(in_path, 'wb') as file_obj:
        writer = csv.writer(file_obj)

        for row in izip(info_source, cycle([13243, 3452345, 234234])):
            writer.writerow(row)
```

Now each `row` is an element from `info_source`, paired with either `13243`, `3452345` or `234234`, cycling on until `info_source` is exhausted.

Comment: Elements from `in_path` will be characters of the file name, won't they? I think there is a bug in the OP's original code re-using this variable.

Comment: @beroe: good point; I've replaced that win a more ephemeral reference to `info_source` instead.

Comment: in_path has values in column 1 I need to preserve - so in this case, is info_source == in_path?

Comment: This does what I'm looking for in columns 2, but how can I start the iteration at row 2 with a header in coulmn 2, row 1?

Comment: @gigawatts: Write the headers outside the loop first.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't make sense to me that your code is iterating over rows in `in_path` while writing to it? Even if that is what you want to do, it only gives you one shot at testing input before you have to recreate your source file.

If you have an input file containing lines with only `object` in it, and want to write your three values in a column next to `object` you can do this:

```
def listplace(in_path):
    with open(in_path, 'r') as file_obj:
        with open(out_path,'wb') as output_obj:
            writefile = csv.writer(output_obj)
            val_list = [13243, 3452345, 234234]  # don't use "list" as a var name

            # iterate over rows in input file, not output file...

            for i,row in enumerate(file_obj):
                 obj_col = split(row)[0].rstrip() # whatever that object value might be

                 selected_val = val_list[i%3]    # use the remainder to select from list

                 writefile.writerow([obj_col,selected_val])
```

You will have to define `in_path` and `out_path`...

This uses the `mod` operation to get `0,1,2` for each line in the file as you go through.